# userdefined javascript function from nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to NodeJS.
How can I execute my own javascript function from NodeJS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create js file, then from command prompt: node -js file path-

example: node C:\app.js

Comment: I actually want to call a javascript function from a separate .js file in to another nodeJS file.

Comment: then you should write this in one.js file: module.exports = function(){ console.log(1); } then include in second.js file: var one = require('./one.js'); one();